# listview not refresh properly after call notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've facing a problem to refresh `listview` after delete item from database.

Problem is that when i'm call `notifyDataSetChanged()` it return a `listView` with removing last index element from list instead of specific index every time (eg i want to delete 2nd index item then after deleting item `listView` show with removing last item every time but actual list and database contain right value).

I cant understand this problem why `notifyDataSetChanged()` method **behave like** this and what is **solution** for it.

Code inside BaseAdapter class:

```
public class CustomReminderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<ReminderData> datalist;
    Viewholder holder;
    private AddReminderHelperDao dao;


    public CustomReminderAdapter(Context context,
            List<ReminderData> datalist) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.datalist = datalist;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return datalist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return datalist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return datalist.get(position).getId();
    }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate( R.layout.custom_list_item, null);
        holder = new Viewholder();
        holder.delete = (LinearLayout) convertView .findViewById(R.id.deletelayout);

        holder.delete.setTag(position);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // datalist contain all values from database
            int positionToRemove = (int)v.getTag();
            int id= datalist.get(positionToRemove).getId();

            try {
                // dao method call for delete from database
                dao.deleteReminder(id);
                datalist.remove(positionToRemove);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                dao.close();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

ViewHolder class:

```
private class Viewholder {
    private TextView titleTextView, timeDetail;
    private ImageView remindertypeImageView,conformimage;
    private ImageView sendwish;
    private LinearLayout topsideLayout, bglayout, bottomsideLayout,
            bottomrightstrip, topLayout, editLayout, snoozedlayout;
    private LinearLayout delete, conform, edit;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please post your full adapter class here.

Comment: @Bhavesh Patadiya ji actually class is too coded so please tell me what you required to see i will post that part....

Comment: datalist is declared in your adapter class or in your main class

Comment: @user3676184 in main class passing through a constructor of BaseAdapter class.

Answer (score 1):

Its very difficult guessing without knowing your full class file. However, you should definitely follow viewholder pattern and change your getview method like below :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final Viewholder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new Viewholder();

            // Initializa your all finviewbyIds here


            //Set tag of position
            holder.delete.setTag(position);

            // Set your holder to convertview for reusing it.
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //Do your business logic here
        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // datalist contain all values from database
                int positionToRemove = (int) v.getTag();
                int id = datalist.get(positionToRemove).getId();

                try {
                    // dao method call for delete from database
                    dao.deleteReminder(id);
                    datalist.remove(positionToRemove);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    dao.close();
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

Change

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate( R.layout.custom_list_item, null);
```

To

```
 convertView = mInflater.inflate( R.layout.custom_list_item, parent,false);
```

Also, update `getItemId()` to

```
 @Override 
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

**Edit :**

```
holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // datalist contain all values from database 
            int positionToRemove = (int)v.getTag();
            int id= datalist.get(positionToRemove).getId();

            try { 
                // dao method call for delete from database 
                dao.deleteReminder(id);
                // Directly pass the object instead of passing any positions
                datalist.remove(datalist.get(positionToRemove));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally { 
                dao.close();
            } 

        } 
    });
```

Comment: ji i will edit my code and i'm also doing same as you suggest please check my edit and give me suggestion for it

Comment: ji please some help me to solve it i google and try many solution from stackoverflow but cant work for me......

Comment: you can put log below the "int positionToRemove = (int) v.getTag();" and check runtime whether your position coming correcty or not.

Comment: sir log cart show correct positionToRemove value and i am also print all value from list before remove() and after remove() it also correct but  when we change fragment  and comes on it (fragment) then listview be fine.....  problem only when i call call notifyDataSetChanged() then it left last position element every time.